# Python3 solution to create all parent directories and file from a relative path [Windows]

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to create all non-existing directories and the file from a relative path but am unable to do so.

Example:

```py
import os

path = os.path.join("folder1", "folder2", "folder3", "file.txt")
os.makedirs(path)  # this creates a directory called 'file.txt' instead of a file.
```

I would like to have the following:
`folder1` > `folder2` > `folder3` > `file.txt`

**Note**: Would be great if anyone has any one-liner solutions for this.

Comment: You’ll have to do this in two passes.  The first using `os.makedirs(path)` to create the structure.  Then use `with open(os.path.join(path, 'file.txt'), 'w') as f: pass` to create the empty file.  (Obviously, where `path` only contains the directories.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know that doesn't exist, but using this function, it can become a one liner:

```
def create_file_in_folders(p):
    folders = p.rsplit("\\", maxsplit= 1)[0]
    os.makedirs(folders)
    with open(p, "w") as f: f.write("")

p = os.path.join("folder2", "folder2", "text.txt")
create_file_in_folders(p)
>>> # now you should find an empty txt file in the newly created folders
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought maybe there was already a function built for this, but this works too.